# How to save file from $request in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

I have a function in controller

```
    public function upload(Request $request)
        {
 $file = $request->file('File');
 $destinationPath = 'uploads';
 $file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
    
        }
```

if i send the $request in log it shows something like this

```
array (
  '_id' => 'tuYDOc644W6DDgAS',
  '_token' => 'FerVRJvJWtnzv91TGuFRpIeT173aD9pH2o9Pqcu9',
  'upload_column' => 'File',
  'id' => 'WU_FILE_0',
  'name' => '134772132_217259409961521_6013657189083751736_o.jpg',
  'type' => 'image/jpeg',
  'lastModifiedDate' => '2/7/2021, 6:44:12 AM',
  'size' => '629882',
  '_file_' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => '134772132_217259409961521_6013657189083751736_o.jpg',
     'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

but this is giving a "Call to a member function move() on null"

i am using [laravel-admin package](https://laravel-admin.org/) , how can i properly save file and get information about the file?

Answer (score 1):

I just found , its bit different with laravel-admin package

the request object is

```
array (

  '_id' => 'tuYDOc644W6DDgAS',

  '_token' => 'FerVRJvJWtnzv91TGuFRpIeT173aD9pH2o9Pqcu9',

  'upload_column' => 'File',

  'id' => 'WU_FILE_0',

  'name' => '134772132_217259409961521_6013657189083751736_o.jpg',

  'type' => 'image/jpeg',

  'lastModifiedDate' => '2/7/2021, 6:44:12 AM',

  'size' => '629882',

  '_file_' => 

  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(

     'test' => false,

     'originalName' => '134772132_217259409961521_6013657189083751736_o.jpg',

     'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',

     'error' => 0,

     'hashName' => NULL,

  )),
)
```

i can get the file name and file like this and store them

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($request->name, $request->_file_);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the it seems that the put method is able to handle the HTTP foundation File class magically

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this.

From:

```
$file = $request->file('File');
```

To:

```
$file = $request-> File; //Use file input tag's name attribute here.
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: i have used your suggested method but still getting 

 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function move() on null 

if i use hasFile method it returns false in $request

Comment: that means your form is not sending file, make sure You are using enctype= multipart/form-data in your blade's form tag.

Comment: i found the file was withing the request object and i can access it like $request->name or $request->_File_ 
it seems strange but i think how it works with the laravel-admin package

Comment: that's what I mentioned in my answer, its not strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel storage: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

just need 3 basic steps

1. create symbolic link from command: php artisan storage:link
2. config your file system in the config directory: public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public')
3. save file: Storage::disk('public')->put('file_name', 'file');

Comment: this method is working creating and storing file but i need to get the file from $request in my function , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps below:

1. Validate the requested file by your valid mimes:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'File' => ['required', 'mimes:jpeg,gif,bmp,png', 'max:2048']
]);
```

2. Get the file from the request

```
$image = $request->file('File');
```

3. Rename the given filename

```
// get the original file name and replace any spaces with _
// For example, Business Cards.png = timestamp()_business_cards.png
$filename = time()."_". preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', strtolower($image->getClientOriginalName()));
```

4. Move the image to the location (public)

```
$tmp = $image->storeAs('uploads', $filename, 'public');
```

Comment: it still not working ,heres the log data
[2021-02-07 12:21:47] local.ERROR: Method App\Admin\Controllers\ClaimController::validate does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method App\\Admin\\Controllers\\ClaimController::validate does not exist. at D:\\ivan\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php:68)
[stacktrace]
#0 D:\\ivan\\app\\Admin\\Controllers\\ClaimController.php(54): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->__call('validate', Array)

Comment: Which version of laravel & PHP you are using?

Comment: heres the composer config
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "dcat-admin-extension/ueditor": "dev-master",
        "dcat/laravel-admin": "^1.7",
        "dcat/page": "dev-master",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },

Comment: Can you do not validate the file and test it?
I mean to pass step number 1.

Comment: some how i could not identify the method you specified in first step ,instead it has something similar hasFile method , i am using a package called dcat-admin

Comment: Use this instead:
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'File' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,gif,bmp,png|max:2048'
]);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your view, in the `form` tag, there is the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute, without this, your form will send character strings.

On the other side in your controller,

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    // Don't forget the validation

    $name = time(). "." . $request->file->extension();
    $destination = "public/your_path"; // You can omit public if you have the necessary configuration for that

    $path = $request->file->storeAs($destination, $name); // $path is the final destination returned by laravel which you can save in the database for later use.
}
```

Tell me if it's helpful